# Manipulating an element based on its location on the page

Tags: javascript

So in my code, when you click an element it will discover the path to that element and alert it. I want to then "save" the path of the element and then upon clicking the button, locate it and add a red border to it.

```js
function nodelistToArray(nodelist) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(nodelist);
}

function traverse(target, chain) {
  if (chain === void 0) {
    chain = [];
  }
  var index = nodelistToArray(target.parentNode.children).filter(function(a) {
    return a.nodeName == target.nodeName;
  }).indexOf(target);
  chain.push({
    element: target,
    index: index
  });
  if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "html") {
    return chain.reverse();
  } else {
     return traverse(target.parentNode, chain);
  }
}
  
document.addEventListener("click", eOnClick, true);

function eOnClick(evt) {
  var chain = traverse(evt.target);
  alert(chain.map(function(elm) {
    return elm.element.nodeName + ' [' + (elm.index).toString() + ']';
  }).join(' > '));
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <ol>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <ol>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<p>1. Click one of the elements above
<br>2. An alert will tell you where this element is located
<br>3. Click the button below to add a red border to the element

<p><button>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to resolve the path of the node, regardless of style needs?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think need to find out the path of the element .You can get the element like this
and apply the css.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
        target.setAttribute('style','border:10px solid red');   
}, false);
```

Comment: What I really want to achieve is to acquire the element as a variable I could use later, like if I was hard-coding it into my javascript to reference.

Comment: you can store the element as variable using your method but can apply the css to the clicked element using the above method